# CONVERTIR ARCHIVO KMZ A XML O CSV C#

Tags: javascript, c#, csv

Hola hoy al trabajo me llego un archivo con coordenadas de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito pasar esto a un CSV o a un campo string para meterlo en la base de datos, alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, las preguntas que no tienen investigacion o algo de trabajo por detras no son bien recibidas, te recomiendo leer esto para que tus futuras preguntas reciban ayuda de la comunidad y a la vez no sean eliminadas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Quiza sea conveniente pasar el .kml a .geoJson. Por otra parte, Qgis puede transformar el .kml en un dump, por ejemplo de Postgres.

Comment: @Ivandez No hay mucho que investigar, a duras penas se encuentra algo de información sobre los ficheros KMZ

Comment: @Emeeus Okey muchas gracias por darme un ruta de comienzo, intentare con esto, estaré informando.

Comment: @Emeeus okey ya logre sacar el archivo en KML y puedo ver los datos, ahora tendría que pasarlo a csv pero no tengo idea de como (soy novato en asp).